# SoundCloud Mobile Error

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, soundcloud

Alright guys,
I'm pretty new to all this so sorry if i don't make sense, I wish to use SoundCloud in my jquery mobile pages. I've got the following iframe code below to use:

```
        <iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/100795671&color=ff6600&auto_play=false&show_artwork=false&sharing=false&download=false&show_playcount=false&liking=false&show_comments=false&auto_advance=false&show_user=false" id="player"></iframe>
        </p>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <button id="play">Play</button>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <button id="pause">Pause</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /grid-b -->
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var iframe = document.querySelector('#player');
            var sc = SC.Widget(iframe);

            sc.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
                var d = document.createTextNode('Ready');
                document.querySelector('body').appendChild(d);
            });

            document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
                sc.play();
                });

            document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function () {
                sc.pause();
                });
          </script>
```

im also calling these js files in the header

```
<script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

The problem i get is it won't play for me on my mobile view, the wavform image also seems to double up and cover the play/pause icon.

Screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/109/qxix.png/

I've tested it on desktop view and there seems to be no issues viewing it that way, here is the page i'm testing it all on at the minute
http://www.blackburnravers.com/test/media/blackburnravers/blackburnravers_androidcore_v3.0.html

Is there out I've done wrong?
Hope somebody can help me out.
Thanks alot,
Blackburn Ravers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to implementation of the Widget API playing sound via external controls isn't possible in iOS – this is because of the asynchronous nature of `postMessage` and the limitation of iOS, that [playback has to be initiated by user](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html).

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you for your reply, that explains why. Thanks. I'm now looking into a new way of using soundcloud, via some SC custom players I've found on github